# NestJS - avoid setContext() in constructor on logger injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

In NestJS I have custom logger:

```
import { Injectable, Logger, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export class LoggerService extends Logger {
  log(message: any) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  error(message: any) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  warn(message: any) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  debug(message: any) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  verbose(message: any) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  setContext(context: string) {
    super.context = context;
  }
}
```

It is registered globally:

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [LoggerService],
  exports: [LoggerService],
})
export class LoggerModule {}
```

Is there any way to somehow pass context on injection in service constructor and avoid execution of logger.setContext(context) in every service - instead just set it in *LoggerService* constructor?

Example usage now:

```
constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {
    this.logger.setContext(ClassName.name);
}
```

Expected usage:

```
constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `private logger: LoggerService`, there's no chance to make that `.setContext(Service.name)` call.

What you could do is something like:
`@Logger(Service.name) private logger: LoggerService`

How? Read this article: [Advanced NestJS: Dynamic Providers](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-dynamic-providers-1ee)